# Changing Worksheet Data in Embedded Excel Worksheet in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been beating my head up against this for way too long and I cannot seem to find any posts on this specific issue:

I have a MS Word 2010 Document that has an embedded Excel worksheet, not linked.  My ultimate goal is to modify the data on that worksheet from MS Access, but for now, I'm just trying to figure out how to reference that underlying worksheet.

I've been able to do it with a Chart, but not an embedded worksheet.

I can locate the object:

```
me.Shapes(1)
```

and even get the alternate text from it:

```
debug.print me.Shapes(1).AlternativeText
```

but cannot figure out how to get to the underlying worksheet.  With a chart, I could simply reference the `me.Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData` and on from there, but there isn't a predefined object for the worksheet itself.

Can anyone help me?  I would be most greatful! :-)

Comment: let's make it clear, what do you mean by 'embedded worksheet'- just few cells which you see as worksheet table or worksheet which is the data background of the chart (you mentioned)?

Comment: Sorry about about that.  It is a "few cells" which I see as a worksheet table. :-)

Comment: I know this is answered, but I figured I'd put this in here.  I've also created another question.  I got it to work fine from within Word, but now I'm trying to get it to work from Access.  I'm able to edit other objects on the Word doc from Access, but it's not working for these embedded excel worksheets.  I get a "type mismatch" on the "Set oleObj = wdDoc.Shapes("tblEBACostHistory").OLEFormat" line.  Any ideas?

Comment: i didn't find the other question as it is not tagged with vba (which I trace). I have no idea what is the problem but see suggestion/question there...

Comment: I'm an idiot!  I kept thinking this was some sort of reference library issue.  Then it dawned on me... when I define the OLEFormat object I have to define it as "Word.OLEFormat".  Now it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should clarify the way you can access (to read and write) any cell in embedded sheet in Word document:

```
Sub Word_Embedded_Sheet()

    Dim oleSH As Object
    Set oleSH = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).OLEFormat

    'few lines to understand where we are...
    With oleSH
        Debug.Print .ClassType
        Debug.Print .Object.Name
        Debug.Print TypeName(.Object)
    'changing cell value
        .Object.sheets(1).Range("a1").Value = 125

    'reading cell value
        Debug.Print .Object.sheets(1).Range("a1").Value

    End With
End Sub
```

Edit: additional information/tip.
Proposed code can seem to be unstable and could not work occasionally. What I have realised is that it is required sometimes to double-click your worksheet in document to allow macro to go to the end.

Comment: Thanks KaxJaw!  Funny thing is, I did pretty much exactly what you have done here.  And it worked, once! Then it stopped, giving me an "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set" error.  And I hadn't changed anything.  That's what I'm dealing with now.  I'll keep at it.  I'm trying to get this to work entirely behind the scenes so there will be no user interaction to "double-click" anything.  May have to do something different if it's going to be unstable.

Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured out what was happening.  My embedded worksheet kept becoming "unembedded" and changed to a picture.  I was trying to close the Word instance of Excel, like I had to do with editing chart data. But when I did that, the worksheet would lose it's connection to Excel and convert to an image.

So, instead of quitting the instance of Excel, I simply did the following:

k, I figured out what was happening.  My embedded worksheet kept becoming "unembedded" and changed to a picture.  I was trying to close the Word instance of Excel, like I had to do with editing chart data. But when I did that, the worksheet would lose it's connection to Excel and convert to an image.

So, instead of quitting the instance of Excel, I simply did the following:

```
SendKeys "{ESC}"
```

Now, I know it's taboo to use the SendKeys command, but it works!